# how can i make it from span to row in grid(EXTJS)?

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

The below code does the colour change of the text in the cell.how can it be applied to apply entire row background colour ????

```
function dataindex(val){
        if(val > 0){
            return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '%</span>';
        }else if(val < 0){
            return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '%</span>';
        }
        return val;
    }
```

Comment: are you trying to apply background color per cell? What exactly is your requirement? I see you have asked similar questions but without a proper requirement nobody can help you!

Comment: @ Abdel Olakara:no.based on some value of cell in a row,colour has to b applied for dat entire row.

Comment: i'm trying in different ways.

Answer (score 3):

You can customize the appearance of grid rows by overriding the `getRowClass` method of `GridView` (see [Ext JS API](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/)).

Quoted example from API documentation - see how getRowClass returns a different css class depending on the condition:

```
viewConfig: {
    forceFit: true,
    showPreview: true, // custom property
    enableRowBody: true, // required to create a second, full-width row to show expanded Record data
    getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rp, ds){ // rp = rowParams
        if(this.showPreview){
            rp.body = '<p>'+record.data.excerpt+'</p>';
            return 'x-grid3-row-expanded';
        }
        return 'x-grid3-row-collapsed';
    }
},
```

After overriding the method, you just need to set up the css definitions with whatever background colors etc. that you wish.

Comment: mi: i mean to apply colour for entire row background.

Answer (score 0):

Like Tommi said, `getRowClass` is what you want to use. If you really want to set the color explicitly, you can append styles to `rowParams.tstyle`:

```
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store) {
        rowParams.tstyle += "color: green;";
    }
},
```

But usually it's better to simply return a class name from `getRowClass` and define the exact colors in CSS file.